# Spring - multiple @Components

Tags: java, spring, annotations, components

Lets assume that I have beans A and B basing on the same class X. Is it possible to apply @Component annotation to class X and make Spring still recognize them separately?

Comment: No... The java language doesn't support inheriting annotations to subclasses.

Comment: It actually does, but the annotation needs to be tagged with `@Inherited`, see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/Inherited.html.  However the Spring annotation `@Component` is not annotated as such.

Comment: Doh. You are right, I was confusing mixing interfaces. But indeed the spring annotations for components are annotated with `@Inherited` and as such don't work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not possible as the Spring annotation `@Component` is not an inheritable annotation.